# \IEEEeqnarraymulticol and long equations

Tags: equations

I am trying to set a long equation using IEEEeqnarray and \IEEEeqnarraymulticol. A simple example is below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}
    {
    fffffffffffffffffffff = ggggggggggggggggggg + hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    } \\ \quad
    &=& kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the "+hhhhhhhhh..." term runs off the page. I would like to take a new line for this term. However, when I try the obvious

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}
    {
    fffffffffffffffffffff = ggggggggggggggggggg \\ + hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    } \\ \quad
    &=& kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
\end{IEEEeqnarray}

\end{document}
```

the document will not compile. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I will not stick with (exotic) `IEEEtrantools`. Simpler is to use `amsmath` (or it improved version `mathtools`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% to determine and show page layout

    \begin{document}
\begin{align}
    \begin{split}
& fffffffffffffffffffff 
    = ggggggggggggggggggg\\
& \hspace{9em} + hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
    \end{split}     \label{eq:upper}        \\
& = kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
                    \label{eq:lower}
\end{align}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used `IEEEeqnarray` but I've used `align` and I am able to reproduce what you want. Its really simple and hassle-free to use `align*`. All that one needs to remember is the insertion of ampersand for proper alignment of the lines in the equation. The output I've got is as below:[image: TeX Output]

I also assume that you intend to display the ampersands rather than using them as alignments ( in the line below `\\ \qquad`). This can be done using a simple `\` before the ampersand.

Additionally, I tried out this code too and it seems to work fine for me
`\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
\IEEEeqnarraymulticol{2}{l}
$fffffffffffffffffffff = ggggggggggggggggggg$ \\$+ hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh$\\
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{document}`

The output isn't so pleasing but you might want to try and align them properly

[image: With IEEEEqnarray]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that I was being a bit of a simpleton. The following does the job.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
    \IEEEeqnarraymulticol{3}{l}
    {
    fffffffffffffffffffff = ggggggggggggggggggg
    } \\ \quad
    && + hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh \\
    &=& kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If this what you looking for? Your solution number also the first part of equation! This is unusual and was reason why I suggest you to use `align` and `split` environments from `amsmath` (which you already load in your example) with some manual adjustment for second part of the first equation.

Comment: It was not the numbering that I was concerned about, it was the alignment problem. Numbering off now. Cheers...